# api for buy/sell bitcoin

Tags: buy-bitcoins

I have recently started a project to build an exchange plateform. I am unable to find an API that provides me an ability to implement a feature to buy and sell bitcoins.

**Can someone please let me know**

1. if an api is available to provide this feature.
2. also if i were to test it, how would i go towards testing that feature.

I have seen some api where there are end points available but it is very risky if end points are changed.

I will really appreciate your help.

Thanks,

Comment: Yes, there are APIs. However, why would other exchanges help you?

Comment: I am not planning to compete with other exchanges, this is something that i am building as part of my capstone project and learning.

Comment: If you're not going to compete, just use the GDAX API. Just be aware that you will get shut down if you are competing.

Comment: https://github.com/danpaquin/gdax-python

Answer (score 3):

A simple google search does the trick.

There are mutiple APIs from major crypto currency exchanges:

- [CoinBase API](https://developers.coinbase.com/docs/wallet/guides/buy-sell)
- [Kraken API](https://www.kraken.com/features/api)